# IF functions depending on row number

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Basically i have a set of data (applications) and i am trying to have a formula which can automatically turn it to a yes for a higher level review based on every 1/10 * 680 (applications)

SO basically If column A says Yes then turn Column B to Yes aswell
But also turn COlumn B to yes if its every 6th or 7th row

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If Cell A1 = "Yes" and if "Yes" for every 6th row then in Cell B1 paste:

`=IF(A1="Yes","Yes",IF(MOD(ROW(A1),6)<>0,"","Yes"))`